# Save Excel file with OLE, Java on Eclipse RCP Application

Tags: java, eclipse, excel, eclipse-rcp, ole

I try to Save an Excel file. The Excel file is a template with makros (*.xltm). I can open the file and edit the content, but if i try to save the destination Excel file is corrupt.
I try to save the file with:

```
int id = _workbook.getIDsOfNames(new String[] {"Save"})[0];
_workbook.invoke(id);
```

or/and

```
_xlsClientSite.save(_file, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try specifying a file format in your Save call.

If you're lucky, you can find the file format code you need in the Excel help.  If you can't find what you need there, you'll have to get your hands dirty using the **OLEVIEW.EXE** program.  There's likely a copy of it sitting on your hard drive somewhere, but if not, it's easy enough to find a copy with a quick Google search.

To use **OLEVIEW.EXE**:

- Run it
- Crack open the 'Type Libraries' entry
- Find the version of Excel that you're using
- Open that item
- Search the enormous pile of text that's displayed for the string 'XlFileFormat'
- Examine the XLFileFormat enum for a code that seems promising

If you are using Office2007 ("Excel12") like I am, you might try one of these values:

- xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled = 52
- xlOpenXMLTemplateMacroEnabled = 53

Here's a method that I use to save Excel files using OLE:

```
/**
 * Save the given workbook in the specified format.
 * 
 * @param controlSiteAuto the OLE control site to use
 * @param filepath the file to save to
 * @param formatCode XlFileFormat code representing the file format to save as
 * @param replaceExistingWithoutPrompt true to replace an existing file quietly, false to ask the user first
 */
public void saveWorkbook(OleAutomation controlSiteAuto, String filepath, Integer formatCode, boolean replaceExistingWithoutPrompt) {
    Variant[] args = null;
    Variant result = null;
    try {
        // suppress "replace existing?" prompt, if necessary
        if (replaceExistingWithoutPrompt) {
            setPropertyOnObject(controlSiteAuto, "Application", "DisplayAlerts", "False");
        }

        // if the given formatCode is null, for some reason, use a reasonable default
        if (formatCode == null) {
            formatCode = 51;    // xlWorkbookDefault=51
        }

        // save the workbook
        int[] id = controlSiteAuto.getIDsOfNames(new String[] {"SaveAs", "FileName", "FileFormat"});
        args = new Variant[2];
        args[0] = new Variant(filepath);
        args[1] = new Variant(formatCode);
        result = controlSiteAuto.invoke(id[0], args);

        if (result == null || !result.getBoolean()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to save active workbook");
        }

        // enable alerts again, if necessary
        if (replaceExistingWithoutPrompt) {
            setPropertyOnObject(controlSiteAuto, "Application", "DisplayAlerts", "True");
        }
    } finally {
        cleanup(args);
        cleanup(result);
    }
}

protected void cleanup(Variant[] variants) {
    if (variants != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < variants.length; i++) {
            if (variants[i] != null) {
                variants[i].dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I try this solution, but the result is an empty Excel file.

Comment: Without any Excel sheets. I use Excel 2010 and try formatCode 52 and 53.

Comment: I don't have Excel 2010 but a little Googling leads me to believe that the codes haven't changed from Excel 2007.  It's not possible to have an Excel workbook with no worksheets in it.  One thing that I have seen is that workbooks created via this OLE mechanism sometimes have bizarre "window positions" inside of the Excel application frame (they are "out of view").  Try opening your generated workbook and then selecting `View->Arrange All->Cascade`, and see if that "pulls the workbook into view."